# STM32L072 ADC slow conversion

Tags: stm32, adc, dma

I am trying to use the ADC on my board that runs at 32 MHz.

I want to sample, using DMA, a signal each 2.5 microseconds (400 kHz) but is seems not feasible.

The ADC seems to be running at 16 MHz so in theory it should be possible. I'll be checking back at the office.

Using my current setting I can sample at 10 kHz but if I try to increase the timer22 I start getting a delay. For example if I set a sample time of 20 kHz I start getting delays and see on my oscilloscope that tim22 is called for the double of time (the entire acquisition lasts for 2 ms instead of 1 ms).

My current settings are: ADC in synchronous mode with prescaler 2 (cannot select prescaler 1 in sync mode), 12 bit resolution, use tim22 on rising edge, sample cycle 39.5 cycles, APB1 32 MHz, APB2 2 MHz(need it for USART).

Furthermore, I am *not* sampling on a fast channel, merely channel 9.

Comment: Why are you running APB2 at 2 MHz, since ADC is on APB2 bus it will now have limited clocks. You don't need such low APB2 frequency for UART. If this is the problem I can post it as an answer.

Comment: The answer was running the ADC in asynchronous mode with software trigger. I have to run APB2 at 2mhz because I have a serial to USB converter. Now i understand why the ADC was so low on sync mode.

Comment: I am sure you don't need to run APB2 at 2 MHz because you have a serial to USB converter. Maybe you are doing something wrong.

Comment: mHz is mili Hertz, meanwhile MHz is mega Hertz,  KHz is Kelvin Hertz, kHz is kilo Hertz.  Use the correct prefix and units.

Comment: @Marco i setted everything in KelvinHertz and the ADC started working. Thanks for the amazing insight!